# Prayer to attain a religious guru or guide?

Tags: rituals, guru

Is there any prayer that can be done to quickly attain a religious guru or guide to better and more accurately study Vedic texts?

Comment: stotra of Rishis, especially Dattatreya.

Comment: Thank you very much!